# How to pass a template type (std::array or std::vector) to a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++14

I have a function template where the return type of the function is the template argument. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction, we can have a template argument deduction with the following examples

```cpp
template<typename To, typename From>
To convert(From f);
```

Now as an example, I want to make a specialized function for this where I passed the following:

```cpp
auto x = convert<std::array>(6000); // the From should be deduced as int.
```

In this case, I want to make a specialized function template, where the sizeof the `From` determines the size of the array , and to keep it simple, assume that `uint8_t` is the type of the array as the data type which represents 1 byte.

Therefore, the type of x should be `std::array<uint8_t, 4>`.

Another example:

```cpp
auto y = convert<std::array>(1.02322); // the From should be deduced as double
```

In this case, the type of y should be `std::array<uint8_t, 8>`.

The second problem is if `std::vector` is passed as a template argument

```cpp
auto x = convert<std::vector>(6000); // the From should be deduced as int
```

The type of x should be `std::vector<uint8_t>`, and the length of the vector is 4

How to make such function template that can accept both std::array and std::vector, and without using any std::span algorithm as I am limited to c++11/14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` and `std::vector` are different kinds of template.

To match `std::vector`, you can have

```
template <template <typename...> class To, typename From>
To<uint8_t> convert(From from);
```

To match `std::array`, you need

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class To, typename From>
To<uint8_t, sizeof(From)> convert(From from);
```

But this is good, because you can't partially specialise a function template. Here you instead have overloads.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8492c7c80a47354e)